# Table keys error in MySQL Syntax

Tags: mysql, error-handling, syntax-error

Can someone help me out with my error;

```
-- Create ordered
CREATE TABLE ordered(
orderID TINYINT UNSIGNED AUTO_INCREMENT,
total_cost DECIMAL(10,2),
customerID TINYINT UNSIGNED,
offercode VARCHAR(15),
CONSTRAINT ordered_pk PRIMARY KEY (orderID)
CONSTRAINT ordered_customerID_fk FOREIGN KEY (customerID) REFERENCES customer(customerID) 
    ON UPDATE CASCADE
CONSTRAINT ordered_offercode_fk FOREIGN KEY (offercode) REFERENCES offer(offercode)
    ON UPDATE CASCADE
);


DESCRIBE ordered;



-- Create line item
CREATE TABLE line_item(
item_number TINYINT UNSIGNED,
orderID TINYINT UNSIGNED,
quantity TINYINT,
shipping_amount DECIMAL(6,2)
CONSTRAINT line_item_pk PRIMARY KEY (item_number, orderID)
CONSTRAINT line_item_item_number_fk FOREIGN KEY (item_number) REFERENCES item(item_number)
    ON UPDATE CASCADE,
CONSTRAINT line_item_orderID_fk FOREIGN KEY (orderID) REFERENCES ordered(orderID)
    ON UPDATE CASCADE
    ON DELETE CASCADE
);

DESCRIBE line_item;
```

I'm getting an error for the ORDERED table for my customerID foreign key and an error on my line_item table for my primary key.

Thanks!

Comment: isn't it that there can be only one auto column and it must be defined as a key.

Comment: I don't know what you mean

Answer (score 0):

Your first error because `customer` table is not exist.

The second error because this line `shipping_amount DECIMAL(6,2)`, add a comma to the ending `shipping_amount DECIMAL(6,2),`

Even thought you will run a way from primary key error, You will face the `item` table error because it is not exist.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't include that I have multiple other tables that aren't listed here, customer being on of them. So customer does exist.